# Difference between CypherResultMode.Projection and CypherResultMode.Set

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

What is difference between CypherResultMode.Projection and CypherResultMode.Set in C#.Net Neo4jclient?

Answer (score 1):

(Context: I'm the author of Neo4jClient.)

These are internal, and you should never have to deal with them.

If you're using them, then you are not using the library the way that I intended, or the way that I documented it.

Regardless, the reason they exist is as follows...

Cypher returns tables. Each row becomes a result object back in C# land.

```
MATCH n-[r]-()
RETURN n as Col1, r as Col2

___________________
|  Col1  |  Col2  |
===================
|    a   |    b   |   <--- this row becomes an object
|    c   |    d   |   <--- this row becomes an object
-------------------
```

Now, in this multi-column scenario, it makes sense that each row is an object. We'd use it like this:

```
foreach (var result in query.Results)
{
    result.Col1;
    result.Col2;
}
```

However, let's say we just want to find all of our users:

```
MATCH (u:User)
RETURN u as User

__________
|  User  |
==========
|    a   |   <--- this row becomes an object
|    c   |   <--- this row becomes an object
----------
```

Following the same logic as before, we could access it like so:

```
foreach (var result in query.Results)
{
    result.User;
}
```

Because each result represents a row, we have to manually go and get the user from the row.

It's much more natural to do this:

```
foreach (var user in query.Results)
{
    user;
}
```

That's what the 'set' mode does. It causes Neo4jClient to 'unwrap' the row when it's deserializing it, and effectively ignore the fact that the results were a table.

It's this piece of plumbing that makes this code possible:

```
var users = graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(u:User)")
    .Return<User>("u")
    .Results;

foreach (var user in users) {}
```

Without it, you would have to write this:

```
public class UserResult
{
    public User u { get; set; }
}

var results = graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(u:User)")
    .Return<UserResult>("u")
    .Results;

foreach (var result in results)
{
    var user = result.u;
}
```

Or, you'd have to use an anonymous type:

```
var results = graphClient.Cypher
    .Match("(u:User)")
    .Return(u => new {
        User = u.As<User>()
    })
    .Results;

foreach (var result in results)
{
    var user = result.User;
}
```

Summary:

- Projection = multiple columns, one object per row, one property per column
- Set = I want to forget about Cypher tables and just get a bunch of objects back